# How to read files written by Spark with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, parquet

When Spark writes dateframe data to parquet file, Spark will create a directory which include several separate parquet files. Code for saving:

```
term_freq_df.write
            .mode("overwrite")
            .option("header", "true")
            .parquet("dir/to/save/to")
```

I need to read data from this directory with pandas:

```
term_freq_df = pd.read_parquet("dir/to/save/to")
```

The error:

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory:
```

How to resolve this problem with the simple method that the two code samples could use same path of files?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Can you show the full error traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, when saving Spark will create multiple parquet files in a directory. To read these files with pandas what you can do is reading the files separately and then concatenate the results.

```py
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "dir/to/save/to"
parquet_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.parquet"))
df = pd.concat((pd.read_parquet(f) for f in parquet_files))
```

Comment: The error is RuntimeError: Decompression 'SNAPPY' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED'], so change to csv format. This is working, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `pandas.read_parquet` can handle reading a directory of multiple (partitioned) parquet files fine. So I am curious to see the full error traceback you get.

To demo that this works fine:

```
In [82]: pd.__version__ 
Out[82]: '0.25.0'

In [83]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b']*2, 'B':[1, 2, 3, 4]})

In [85]: df.to_parquet("test_directory", partition_cols=['A'])
```

This created a "test_directory" folder with multiple parquet files. I can read those back in using pandas:

```
In [87]: pd.read_parquet("test_directory/")
Out[87]: 
   B  A
0  1  a
1  3  a
2  2  b
3  4  b
```

Comment: My pandas version is 0.23.4. I try to run your code after updating to 0.25.0, till get error: RuntimeError: Compression 'snappy' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']

Comment: OK, but that is an error not related to the directory problem (you cite a different error in the original question). This comes from writing the parquet file with the `fastparquet` engine. You can pass `compression='GZIP'` to `to_parquet` to avoid this error.

Comment: Note that the multiple files in this case is due to the use of Spark. Spark will save each data partition (default to 200) as a separate file when saving. I'm not sure if pandas can handle this (I didn't actually try though) which is why I gave the answer above.

Comment: Yes, pandas (with pyarrow or fastparquet under the hood) should normally handle this well. If there is a specific case that does not work, it's a bug that would be welcome to be reported.